# Will I have multicollinearity with the following dummy variable and continuous explanatory variable?

Tags: regression, econometrics

Suppose I am trying to estimate productivity $Y_{it}$, and in my regression model -- along with other explanatory variables -- I have a dummy variable $D_{it}$ if the number of employees for a firm is more than 100 employees in time $t$, and I have another explanatory variable $X_{it}$ that is the number of employees for a firm (mind you this is panel data).

Will the model suffer from multicollinearity in this case? What if I lag the number of employees variable? Would this help if there is multicollinearity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, no.

You would have
$$D_{it}:=\mathbb{I}(X_{it}>100),$$
which is a *nonlinear* transformation of $X_{it}$, namely a step function. You could have multicollinearity in the (practically unlikely) case that all small firms have the same number of employees and all large firms have the same number of employees. As an example, suppose all small firms are only run by their owner (no employees) and all large firms have 200 employees. Then,
$$X_{it}=200\cdot D_{it}$$